# Generic higher-order function reference error

Tags: generics, rust, higher-order-functions

I've been banging my head against this one all night. I'm trying to implement a `to_hash_map` method so I can do:

```
struct Person {
    id: i32,
    first_name: &'static str,
}

fn main() {
    let brad = Person {
        id: 1,
        first_name: "brad",
    };
    let barb = Person {
        id: 2,
        first_name: "Barb",
    };
    let a = vec![brad, barb];
    let key_func = |i: &Person| -> i32 { i.id };
    let value_func = |i: &Person| -> &str { i.first_name };
    let map = a.iter().to_hash_map(key_func, value_func);
    println!("{:?}", map)
}
```

and hopefully get the HashMap

```
{
 1: "brad",
 2: "barb"
}
```

Here's my best shot at it:

```
trait ToHashMap<T,K,V, FK, FV>
    where K:Hash,
          K:Eq,
          FK:Fn(&T)->K,
          FV:Fn(&T)->V {

    fn to_hash_map(&self, key_func: FK, value_func: FV) -> HashMap<K, V>;
}

impl<T, K, V, FK, FV, I> ToHashMap<T, K, V, FK, FV> for I
    where K: Hash,
          K: Eq,
          FK: Fn(&T) -> K,
          FV: Fn(&T) -> V,
          I: Iterator<Item = T>
{
    fn to_hash_map(&self, key_func: FK, value_func: FV) -> HashMap<K, V>{
        let mut hm: HashMap<K, V> = HashMap::new();
        loop {
            match self.next() {
                Some(x) => {
                    hm.insert(key_func(&x), value_func(&x));
                }
                None => break,
            }
        }
        hm
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
error: type mismatch: the type `[closure@src/main.rs:92:20: 92:48]` implements the trait `for<'r> core::ops::Fn<(&'r Person,)>`, but the trait `for<'r> core::ops::Fn<(&'r &Person,
)>` is required (expected &-ptr, found struct `Person`) [E0281]
src/main.rs:94     let map = a.iter().to_hash_map(key_func, value_func);
```

I feel like I'm so close. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: It would be great if you could post a MVCE, using https://play.rust-lang.org/ . You are close, just missing a self-contained example.

Comment: I would move most of the type parameters from the trait to the trait method. `T` needs to stay on the trait, otherwise you can't properly bound `I` in your `impl`, but the other type parameters have no relation to the type the trait is implemented on, and are only meaningful during the call to `to_hash_map`. [Here's the code, based on Matthieu M.'s answer.](http://is.gd/vgBwBm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are indeed very close.

The first issue you face is that `iter()` produces an `Iterator::Item` of type `&Person` and therefore `&x` which you pass to your closure is of type `&&Person`.

You can either alter the type of the closure to take a `&&Person` or alternatively consume the vector `a` using `into_iter`.

Another slight issue that I encountered is that you cannot take the iterator by immutable reference: you need to modify the iterator to iterate. Taking the iterator by value is simpler.

All in all, with those two tweaks we can get (consuming the vector):

```
trait ToHashMap<T, K, V, FK, FV>
    where K: Hash,
          K: Eq,
          FK: Fn(&T)->K,
          FV: Fn(&T)->V {

    fn to_hash_map(self, key_func: FK, value_func: FV) -> HashMap<K, V>;
}

impl<T, K, V, FK, FV, I> ToHashMap<T, K, V, FK, FV> for I
    where K: Hash,
          K: Eq,
          FK: Fn(&T) -> K,
          FV: Fn(&T) -> V,
          I: Iterator<Item = T>
{
    fn to_hash_map(self, key_func: FK, value_func: FV) -> HashMap<K, V> {
        let mut hm: HashMap<K, V> = HashMap::new();
        for x in self {
            hm.insert(key_func(&x), value_func(&x));
        }
        hm
    }
}
```

And then [it compiles and runs](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=672dda60ce98c0482ebe&version=stable) and produces:

> ```
> {2: "Barb", 1: "brad"}
> ```

as expected.

Comment: Great answer! I learned a lot from this (I am just starting my Rust journey).

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: Welcome on the train, beware some say it's an addictive language ;)

Comment: Thanks! It seems so obvious when you see the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `a.iter()` returns an iterator whose item is `&Person`. Your trait bounds for the `ToHashMap` impl require that the key and value functions take a `&T`, where `T = Item`, so `T = &Person`, and thus the function argument is `& &Person`, which doesn't match your function.

You have to relax the bounds somehow, though I'm afraid my Rust knowledge is not sufficient to say exactly how.